# Создание списка из словаря по списку со значениями ключей этого словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Есть список с ID и словарь с ключами со значениями этих ID.

Нужно сравнить их, и если есть такие ID, то вывести их в новый список.

Что есть:

```
items = {1: 'Русский язык', 2: 'Математика', 3: 'Физика', 4: 'Химия', 5: 'Информатика и ИКТ'}

values = [2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5]
```

Что нужно получить:

```
['Математика', 'Математика', 'Информатика и ИКТ', 'Информатика и ИКТ', 'Физика', 'Физика', 'Информатика и ИКТ', 'Информатика и ИКТ']
```

Comment: `result = list(filter(None, (items.get(value) for value in values)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = [items.get(x, "не найдено") for x in values]
```

---

результат:

```
In [55]: res
Out[55]:
['Математика',
 'Математика',
 'Информатика и ИКТ',
 'Информатика и ИКТ',
 'Физика',
 'Физика',
 'Информатика и ИКТ',
 'Информатика и ИКТ']
```

Comment: Про добавление лишних строк ничего не было сказано.

Comment: @вася, это бесплатный бонус)

Answer (score 0):

```
items = {1: 'Русский язык', 2: 'Математика', 3: 'Физика', 4: 'Химия', 5: 'Информатика и ИКТ'}

values = [2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5]

result = []
# result = [items[id] for id in values if id in items]

for id in values:
  if id in items:
    result.append(items[id])

print(result)
```